# What is the meaning of "Empty matches are included in the result."?

Tags: python, python-re

I am referring to the documentation of the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function:

What is the meaning of *"Empty matches are included in the result."*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen when you use groups that matches empty string , example:

```
 print(re.findall(r'(\w)(\d?)(\w)', "bc"))
```

OUPUT:

```
[('b', '', 'c')]
```

Here group `(\d?)` matches `''` and is included in the result.

Comment: An empty group doesn't equal an empty match. `(\w)|(\d)` doesn't produce any empty matches.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks for the correction, actually it matches `''`, but why it produces two elements?

Comment: Ok so here empty refers to empty with respect to grouping

Comment: Yes if you have `n` capturing group every tuple in the list will contains `n` element in the same order as the groups.

Answer (score 3):

It just means when the match is “” or an empty string, that it is included in the list of results.

Answer (score 2):

Zero-length matches, or empty matches.

A Regular Expression is made of boundaries definitions, or anchors, for instance the operator `^`. Once the anchor is hit, you have a match, which can be "empty", that is immediately followed by another anchor.

Answer (score -1):

If  a subject is an empty string then fullmatch() evaluates to True for any regex that can find a ... The overall regex match is not included in the tuple, unless you place the entire ... appear in the regular expression, as raw strings do not offer a means to escape it.